# How to recover deleted files in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, file-recovery

Is it possible to recover my deleted files in Mac OS X (after I emptied the trash also)? In Windows I can recover the deleted files using file recovery software. What options are available in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a nice guide [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100524162402/http://www.squidoo.com/recovertrashmac)-- that walks you through the steps of recovering "deleted" files in OS X (using freeware).

Keep in mind that until you recover the files in question, you want to minimize writes to the disk as they can potentially overwrite the deleted files.

Comment: I would add a hint for the next time: after recovering your files you might consider some backup solutions.

Comment: Note the link has since gone dead, but there are snapshots available from the Wayback Machine, such as [this one from May 2010](http://web.archive.org/web/20100524162402/http://www.squidoo.com/recovertrashmac).

Answer (score 6):

The software in the [squidoo page](http://www.squidoo.com/recovertrashmac) that @tj111 recommended needs money to pay for the last recovery step. See [this blog article](http://data-security-freeware.blogspot.com/2011/05/truly-free-mac-data-recovery-software.html) for truly free Mac data recovery programs.

- [Time Machine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427)
- [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)
- [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)
- [Exif Untrasher](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/exif-untrasher/)